# Change brightness of video and save in photo library in Objective-C, XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, gpuimage

I am developing and app for iOS platform. The app is about video editing, I want to give users option to change the brightness of the video before saving. I am using GPUImage library for video editing, is there any way I can change the brightness of the video and save it in the photo library. Thanks

P.S. I tried finding the similar issue, sorry if the answer to this question already exist, i could not find that.